# Trigger a mouse click on the element under the cursor

Tags: jquery, click, simulate

Is it possible to simulate left mouse click on the element that lies beneath the mouse cursor?

Comment: To achieve what, precisely?

Comment: ^^ This.  You may be doing yourself a favour by answering, as this has XY Problem written all over it!

Answer (score 5):

You can [fire a click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) on the document:

```
$(document).click();
```

If you want the element **under the cursor** to be clicked then it's slightly more complicated:

```
var mousePosition;
$(window).on('mousemove', function (e) { 
  mousePosition = {
    x: e.clientX,
    y: e.clientY
  }
});

function makeClick () {
  var el = document.elementFromPoint(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y);
  $(el).click();
}
```

When you want a click under the cursor, call `makeClick()`.

Comment: @Paulius You didn't say anything in your question about wanting links to be clicked.

Comment: in your case:

$(document).click();

Where would the click done? I mean if a mouse cursor id on the link than it should be clicked or not?

Comment: @Paulius Okay so you want whatever is under the cursor to be clicked? Because that's a different question :)

Comment: ,sorry for wrong question at first. Yes I would like whatever is under cursor to be clicked.

Comment: Thank you but it is still not working. I put the code here: My code is here: http://demo.kitoks.com/paulius/test/test.php I also posted the code in answers below.

Comment: @Paulius I see what the problem is, `click` events don't work on links like that. It is actually clicking the link, it just wont follow it. If you wanted to redirect you'd have to do `window.location = $(el).attr('href')`

Answer (score -1):

To simulate a click with jQuery it woild be:

```
$("item").click();
```

In Javascript:

```
 document.getElementById('item').click();
```

Comment: I don't need a click on a certain element. But just simple mouse click (anywhere where the cursor is).